Type for ArrayIndexed Types in Typescript
I have a array which contains info like this [SOP:number,PCKNO:number,LEN:number,PAY:string,EOP:number] and this keeps repeating which comes in an array of packets:any[].
Question is how can i device a type for this in typescript? such that intelisense prompts me the name when for the correct index.
The constraint is I cannot change the array structure into sub array of type, i just need better typings not to add overhead on the code by running flat()
is there any way for this?
Example:
const incomingStream=[]; //This is what i get as input into a function,type is any[]
// From some documentation i know at index 0 of the above i have SOP which is a Number, at index 1 EOP:Number and this repeats.

//Question is how can i apply typings(I mean labels here of SOP,EOP etc, not actual data type) to this array, so that i can get some intellisense help without changing array.


Can you share a code example when you use flat()?

@R.M.Reza added code to explain better, btw array.flat() is just one method which has to be used on pckt[] to get the original structure back.. which is the constraint not changing the code for typing info

(didn't downvote) Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our IDEs to get started on this. It would help if you defined pckt1, pckt2, etc., and made sure your code was syntactically valid without typos. And maybe show some use case and expectations so we can test against it? Right now you're just saying "will not work" but I'm not completely sure what you're doing. Maybe that you're looking for something like this. If so, I'll write an answer explaining once you provide a [mre]. If not, hopefully you can clarify in an [edit] as well.

@jcalz I am trying to apply typing to a any[], as per some documentation.. i have updated the code above see if that helps... to be honest there is nothing to run for example in code.

You should be able to provide a [mre] even if there's "nothing to run". It can be a toy example. We need something to test against. I gather that you want a type that looks like Pckt | [...Pckt, ...Pckt] | [...Pckt, ...Pckt, ...Pckt] | ⋯ but TS has no way to represent such an infinite/recursive union. The closest I can come is to validate a type as shown in this playground link I provided above. Is it close to what you want, maybe? How can we proceed?

@jcalz i think you gave the answer "TS has no way to represent such an infinite/recursive union", its not infinite though if you simply mod the index we should be able to produce a typing label in intelisnese i think..

I'm confused why modding the index means it's not infinite. Certainly there are an infinite number of whole numbers n even if n mod 5 can only take on 5 values. How do you propose to make "modding the index" connect to IntelliSense? It's not like TS knows at the type level that 16 % 5 is equivalent to 1. You could almost use { [k: \${number}${0 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 9}`]: number, [k: `${number}${3 | 8}`]: string }` but that's more trouble than it's worth. Did you look at this playground link? Have you tried producing a [mre] like I asked?

I am confused on your question on whether you want to cast data types to the values of the array or assign labels to each value. So, for convience, I will try and provide answers for both:
Types
If the documentation defines all of the types at each index, you can use tuples. TypeScript can type tuples like so:
type Packet = [number, number, number, string, number];
const packet: Packet = [57, 23, 45, "hello", 345];
console.log(typeof packet[1]); // number
console.log(typeof packet[3]); // string

This way, when you index the tuple, you get the correct type. However, tuples are of fixed size and require you to know the size of your array prior to running the code. (NOTE: this Variadic Tuple Types in TypeScript 4.0 might contradict this point and may be of interest to you).
Another method is to use Type Narrowing. If you know your array will contain either type number or strings, you can use type narrowing to idenitify if its a string or number:
if (typeof value === "string") {
    // code for handling strings
} else {
    // code for handling numbers
}

TypeScript also offer Type Predicates which is a more advanced version of type narrowing; usually used for differentiating interfaces, they can also be used to identify a values type given extra information such as the values key or index in an object or array respectively.
Labels
For labels, I would recommend using either enums to index the array.
enum Labels {
    SOP,
    PCKNO,
    LEN,
    PAY,
    EOP,
    ...
};
const sop = incomingStream[Labels.SOP];

Enums are greate as they provide reverse mapping but I always use prefer using objects because you can iterate through each key-pair value using the methods in the JavaScript provided Object class:
const labels = {
    SOP: 0,
    PCKNO: 1,
    LEN: 2,
    PAY: 3,
    EOP: 4,
    ...
}

Hope this helps!
